# How can I superimpose Pulse signal

Tags: high-frequency, modulation

I designed this circuit, put V1 as sinusoidal source and output was good at oscilloscope.However when I changed V1 to pulse signal there was no output on oscilloscope.

Thanks to tell me if pulse signal can be superimposed with this kind of circuit.

It would be much appreciated if you can guide me to some IC that can transmit VHF(tv signals) at 3v to 9v.This will help me to proceed without designing such circuits.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by superimposed?

Comment: superimposing is the process of putting intelligence signal on carrier wave.

Comment: What frequency was your sine? What width was the pulse?

Comment: I think the industry term is "modulation". Is this like what you're looking for: http://www.linear.com/product/LT5512

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a common base small signal bandpass filter with an input clamp diode D1.
It would serve to amplify sine waves within the range of the filter for < 100mV input approximately and have a fairly high gain but very high output impedance which effectively loads the Q of the filter. I see R3 the load is 1G but I suspect any scope is 1M or 10M.

A Pulse going thru a BPF should generate a sinewave if the freq and level are within range. Otherwise you get unexpected non-linear output or nothing.

This is not a linear pulse mixing circuit such as used to create TV baseband signals.

TV or video signals use Sync pulse input to clamp the AC couple video signal either on the sync tip or the back porch to ground to take an AC coupled signal and restore it to DC with say a negative sync tip and positive video analog signal after the back porch switch is opened and the video signal is allowed thru.

If you have a TV signal, this circuit has nothing to do with VHF or TV signals, so please describe your goal.